# Using Delimiter for loop in Apple script

Tags: applescript

I have a small actionscript.

set lf to ASCII character 10
set csvFile to (choose file with prompt "Select a file to read:")
open for access csvFile
set contentOfCsv to (read csvFile using delimiter {",", lf})
close access csvFile

I want to run a loop to make stuff for each of the parts of "contentOfCsv".

How do I do that?

Thanks
/Erik

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
repeat with aPiece in contentOfCsv
    display dialog aPiece
    -- replace display dialog with code for aPiece
end repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this

```
set lf to ASCII character 10
set csvFile to (choose file with prompt "Select a file to read:")
open for access csvFile
set contentOfCsv to (read csvFile using delimiter {",", lf})
close access csvFile

repeat with theItem in contentOfCsv
  -- Do stuff
end repeat
```

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it and added the post before I had seen your post.. I voted you up thou. ;)

Comment: Happy to help. If I answered your question, accept it by clicking the check mark so other user know the question has been answered.